# Issue with Rule squid:S1166 - Using Util method to log exception

Tags: java, sonarqube

We are using util method to handle a caught exception. We are getting this Sonar Qube violation "Either log or rethrow this exception", even we are logging the exception from Util method.

Example code:

```
catch (Exception e) {
            LogUtils.logErr(e);
        }


LogUtils.logErr(e):

public static void logErr(Throwable e) {
        StackTraceElement[] ste = Thread.currentThread()
                .getStackTrace();
        String className = ste[2].getClassName();
        String methodName = ste[2].getMethodName();
        logger.error(buildMessage(className, methodName, ""), e);
        sendEmail(null, e);
    }
```

Please let me know if there is a work around to make sonar ignore this kind of usage.
It looks like an issue with the rule provided. Please confirm..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize, but it is too long for a comment...

What is your environment? How do you execute analysis?

I created two classes:

```
public class S1166 {

    public static Integer parse(String text) {
        try {
            return Integer.parseInt(text);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LogUtils.log(e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

LogUtils:

```
public final class LogUtils {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("name");

    private LogUtils() {
        // blocks the possibility to create a new instance
    }

    public static void log(Throwable e) {
        StackTraceElement[] ste = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
        String className = ste[2].getClassName();
        String methodName = ste[2].getMethodName();
        logger.log(Level.FINEST, String.format("%s#%s", className, methodName), e);
    }
}
```

SonarQube didn't find any issue.

Environment:

- SonarQube 7.0
- SonarJava 5.2

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have verified again and its working fine.

Comment: I was logging just exception message instead of complete exception at some places is causing the issue and I have overlooked it, Sorry for eating your time:(